# Memory leak in SBCL's REPL

Tags: memory-leaks, common-lisp, sbcl

I'm somewhat baffled by the following behaviour of SBCL garbage collector in REPL. Define two functions:

```
(defun test-gc ()
  (let ((x (make-array 50000000)))
    (elt x 0)))

(defun add-one (x) (+ 1 x))
```

Then run

```
(add-one (test-gc))
```

I would expect that nothing references the original array anymore. Yet, as (room) reports, the memory is not freed. I would understand, if I ran (test-gc) directly, then some reference could have been stuck somewhere in SLIME or in

```
(list * ** ***)
```

But was is the case here? Thanks, Andrei.

**Update** Some time ago I filed a bug. It was recently confirmed. See:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/sbcl/+bug/936304

Comment: you may want to ask this question on the SBCL mailing list

Comment: ... and maybe post a follow-up of their replies here. BTW, why is 'closure' in the title of the question? I don't see any closures in the code of the question.

Comment: I've tried the same code in CLISP, no problems. The git version of SBCL still has this issue, so I submitted a bug report: (https://bugs.launchpad.net/sbcl/+bug/936304). Regarding the closure remark, there is no closure :)

Comment: As I mentioned in that bug report, the bug is still present, though marked as closed. I also reported the similar https://bugs.launchpad.net/sbcl/+bug/1009267. The developers seem remarkably (and disturbingly) uninterested in these issues, even though it is a significant problem in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just because nothing references the objects anymore doesn't mean that the memory will be reclaimed. The garbage collector will be run some time in the future, and often the only guarantee that you get is that it will be run before you get an out of memory error.

Another thing that may happen here is that you are looking at the Lisp process memory usage. When memory is CG'ed it is generally not returned to the operating system. Instead, the memory is simply marked as free on the heap, and can be used in future memory allocations.

Comment: Valid points, I did not think of that. So I did a further test: evaluating `(add-one (test-gc))` a couple of times. If either point is valid, then I should never run out of memory. However, after a couple of evaluations I got: "Heap exhausted". So it does not seem the memory is getting freed or reused.

Comment: I don't see this issue in SBCL 1.0.53 on Linux

Comment: Funny. I used 1.0.54. I've just tried 1.0.53, but I still get the error (also on Linux). If the error does not occur for you also in the git version, you might consider sharing on (https://bugs.launchpad.net/sbcl/+bug/936304).

Answer (score 1):

SBCL only...

`(gc :full t)`

This will forcibly kick off a garbage collection across all generations. I noticed SBCL was holding onto a ton of memory a few days ago and used this to drop the memory down to the "true" usage.

I then wrote an ensure-gc macro to wrap my garbagey computation & experimentation stuff in. I'll paste it in when I get home if I remember... it's nothing fancy.

Comment: Forced garbage collection works, but only after I have evaluated (add-one (test-gc)) more than once. Funny.

Comment: @Andrei: I had to pass in :full to ensure that it goes through all generations.